# Forking an existing gitlab project under my user namespace with the same group name as the original repo

Tags: gitlab

How could I fork an existing gitlab project which exists at: https://gitlab.com/organisation/custom-group/custom-project under my own user namespace: https://gitlab.com/my-user/custom-group/custom-projet ?

Because here https://gitlab.com/groups/new#create-group-pane it's not possible to create a group in my own namespace, e.g. it will necessarily be created at https://gitlab.com/custom-group whereas I want it under https://gitlab.com/my-user/custom-group

On the other hand, if I click on the fork button in the original organization repository, there is no option to create a sub-group in my own namespace at this stage:
https://gitlab.com/organisation/custom-group/custom-project/-/forks/new

[image]

so this will create https://gitlab.com/my-user/custom-project instead of https://gitlab.com/my-user/custom-group/custom-project

I certainly missed something *really* obvious but it has been 2h that I'm losing myself in the documentation without finding anything relevant to solve this "problem".

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say, what you're looking for is just not possible.

As you noticed, it's not possible to create groups "inside" of your username path. This is because your user's namespace and a group namespace work differently.

The [namespaces documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/namespace/) explicitly states this:

> You cannot create subgroups in a personal namespace.

The only way to get the *path* you're looking for would be to change your username and create a group with your "old" username, because namespace paths are unique across both personal and group namespaces. Meaning, you cannot create a group with `my-user` path to get `gitlab.com/my-user` since it's taken by your user.

So if you're willing to give up `my-user` as your username, then you would:

1. [Change your username](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/#change-your-username) to something else.
2. [Create a group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/manage.html#create-a-group) with the path `my-user`.
3. [Create a subgroup](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/subgroups/#create-a-subgroup) in `my-user` group to get `my-user/custom-group`.